# reduce time of sequence calculate by using parallel computing

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing

I try to reduce calculating time but i don't know how to. I think its call parallel computing.

for my code i calculate 19 periods of Exponential moving average(ema) value of 835 stocks. each stock have 3 time frames that is day week and month.

```
stock_names = [835 names]
ema_periods = [5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 75, 90, 100, 200]
ema_day = dict()
ema_week = dict()
ema_month = dict()

elapsed_time = 0

for name in stock_names:
    stock_data_day = get_data(name, 'day', 0, 0)
    stock_data_week = get_data(name, 'week', 0, 0)
    stock_data_month = get_data(name, 'month', 0, 0)

    start = time.time()
    for periods in ema_periods:
        ema_day[periods] = ema(stock_data_day['close'], periods)
        ema_week[periods] = ema(stock_data_week['close'], periods)
        ema_month[periods] = ema(stock_data_month['close'], periods)
    end = time.time()
    elapsed_time = elapsed_time + (end - start)

print('time : ', elapsed_time )
```

output:

```
>>> time :  3.693106174468994
```

I want to get suggestion of how to reduce the time. I need to seperate to 19 processes by ema periods or just 3 processes by timeframe or both. What library that i suppossed to use. or some example to read and try.
Because I have to use ema to calculate something such as the crossover of two ema periods.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure `ema(..)` is the bottleneck. Before you parallelize something you better know what piece of code you should run on multiple cores.

Comment: You can look at pyspark : http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/python-programming-guide.html. It is a good start for parallel computing.